# MSB4018 Error - Resolve Package Dependencies and Resolve Package Assets tasks failed unexpectedly .net5 - Visual Studio 22

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, .net-core, visual-studio-2022

I have a .net5 project and I need to debug a library used by this project. To do so, I have unistalled the NuGet package of my library and add the project reference to my project.
Now, I can not build the project.
After the build I get the following errors:

```
The "ResolvePackageDependencies" task failed unexpectedly.
System.ArgumentException: An item with the same key has already been added.
   at System.ThrowHelper.ThrowArgumentException(ExceptionResource resource)
   at System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2.Insert(TKey key, TValue value, Boolean add)
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.ToDictionary[TSource,TKey,TElement](IEnumerable`1 source, Func`2 keySelector, Func`2 elementSelector, IEqualityComparer`1 comparer)
   at Microsoft.NET.Build.Tasks.ResolvePackageDependencies.GetPackageAndFileDependencies(LockFileTarget target)
   at Microsoft.NET.Build.Tasks.ResolvePackageDependencies.RaiseLockFileTargets()
   at Microsoft.NET.Build.Tasks.ResolvePackageDependencies.ExecuteCore()
   at Microsoft.NET.Build.Tasks.TaskBase.Execute()
   at Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.TaskExecutionHost.Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.ITaskExecutionHost.Execute()
   at Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.TaskBuilder.<ExecuteInstantiatedTask>d__26.MoveNext() Project.Namespace C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\6.0.202\Sdks\Microsoft.NET.Sdk\targets    C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\6.0.202\Sdks\Microsoft.NET.Sdk\targets\Microsoft.PackageDependencyResolution.targets
```

And

```
The "ResolvePackageAssets" task failed unexpectedly
System.ArgumentException: An item with the same key has already been added.
   at System.ThrowHelper.ThrowArgumentException(ExceptionResource resource)
   at System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2.Insert(TKey key, TValue value, Boolean add)
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.ToDictionary[TSource,TKey,TElement](IEnumerable`1 source, Func`2 keySelector, Func`2 elementSelector, IEqualityComparer`1 comparer)
   at Microsoft.NET.Build.Tasks.ProjectContext.GetTopLevelDependencies(LockFile lockFile, LockFileTarget lockFileTarget)
   at Microsoft.NET.Build.Tasks.ResolvePackageAssets.CacheWriter.ComputePackageExclusions()
   at Microsoft.NET.Build.Tasks.ResolvePackageAssets.CacheWriter..ctor(ResolvePackageAssets task)
   at Microsoft.NET.Build.Tasks.ResolvePackageAssets.CacheReader.CreateReaderFromDisk(ResolvePackageAssets task, Byte[] settingsHash)
   at Microsoft.NET.Build.Tasks.ResolvePackageAssets.CacheReader..ctor(ResolvePackageAssets task)
   at Microsoft.NET.Build.Tasks.ResolvePackageAssets.ReadItemGroups()
   at Microsoft.NET.Build.Tasks.ResolvePackageAssets.ExecuteCore()
   at Microsoft.NET.Build.Tasks.TaskBase.Execute()
   at Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.TaskExecutionHost.Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.ITaskExecutionHost.Execute()
   at Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.TaskBuilder.<ExecuteInstantiatedTask>d__26.MoveNext() Project.Namespace   C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\6.0.202\Sdks\Microsoft.NET.Sdk\targets  C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\6.0.202\Sdks\Microsoft.NET.Sdk\targets\Microsoft.PackageDependencyResolution.targets
```

There are no duplicates packages in the csproj.
How can I solve this?
I have already tried to:

- Delete bin, obj and .vs folder
- Restore Nuget packages
- Clear all NuGet cache

Thanks.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I found the solution. The problem was that another Solution project still referenced the NuGet package and not the local project. So it was enough to remove the dependency and add the reference to the local package.

Answer (score 0):

My problem was with Nuget Package which was not exist

```
<PackageReference Include="System.Collections.Immutable" Version="1.2.5.0" />
```

Solution

```
<PackageReference Include="System.Collections.Immutable" Version="7.0.0" />
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case, the deeper error looked something like this:

```
Could not find SDK "Microsoft.UniversalCRT.Debug, Version=10.0.18362.0"
```

This was because I didn't have the correct Windows SDK installed. In my case, I had to install `Windows 10 SDK (10.0.18362.0)` in `Visual Studio -> Tools -> Get Tools and Features...`.

See [this response to an issue on the WinUI Gallery](https://github.com/microsoft/WinUI-Gallery/issues/871#issuecomment-1451084012).

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same error for unrelated reasons.
Running:

```
dotnet restore
```

from CLI in the solution root directory gave me some better info on what was actually going on.